# Error : Table Insertion returns error in vb.net and msacess

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, insert-into

I am new to vb.net and I am trying to insert a values from vb.net to msacess. I know alredy have a answer for this question here but those answers were not solving my problems so I post again

I am getting an error while inserting data into a database.

Ms-acess :

```
table name: reg
_________________
field |datatype
__________________
id    |autonum
fname |text
lname |text
course|text
fees  |number
amount|number
bal   |number
```

The error is:

> Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.

Code:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If (TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Or TextBox4.Text = "" Or TextBox5.Text = "" Or TextBox6.Text = "") Then
            MessageBox.Show("Field Not Empty")
        End If
        connection = New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnect").ConnectionString)
        connection.Open()
        command = New OleDbCommand("insert into reg values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "'," + TextBox4.Text + "," + TextBox5.Text + "," + TextBox6.Text + ")", connection)

        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connection.Close()

        MessageBox.Show("Data Added")
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL string must list the field names, probably:

```
"insert into reg (fname, lname, course, fees, amount, bal) values ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "'," + TextBox4.Text + "," + TextBox5.Text + "," + TextBox6.Text + ")"
```